# How to apply vlookup with an additional condition if another column contains a word in the header of the initial table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to transfer data from one table to another with 2 conditions. I can apply vlookup on country but the other one is if another column contains the word in the other table heads.
I tried something with countif and vlookup but i cannot figure it out.

In the picture you see I would like to have 10 for belgium because it contains the word "people" in column Thing; and 45 for Germany because it contains the work "cars" in column thing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K3</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(I3,$A$3:$A$4,FILTER($B$3:$D$4,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$D$2,J3))))
```

---

One single dynamic array spill

[image]

---

```
=MAP(I3:I4,J3:J4,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP(x,$A$3:$A$4,FILTER($B$3:$D$4,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$D$2,y))))))
```

---